# Automatically see high-level instructions when stopped by breakpoint in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

How can I automatically see current 10 instructions whenever my program stopped by breakpoint in gdb?
(not machine instruction but high level instruction e.g

```
int a = 10;
int b = 12;
   ...
print("a = %d, b = %d\n");
```

To do this manually, I have to use 'list' command to see the instructions.

What command should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `gdb -w` or `gdb -tui` to get a "windowed" interface rather than just the bare command line

Comment: or use `ctrl+x a` key binding to switch to TUI mode and back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using `tui` or an Emacs `gud` mode, you could define [hook-stop](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html):

```
(gdb) define hook-stop
>list
>end
```